Verifying Downtrend by Using For Loop in Pinescript
I wand to use For Loop to check if in the last 5 Days the Daily Open was lower than the Previous Day Daily Open and get alerted if all 5x OPEN were consecutively lower, thus confirming a downtrend. Any ideas or links are highly appreciated.
I tried to code something, but because I am a relatively new to programming, it does not look to work.


Please add your code as text, not as an image.

You don't need a for loop for that. You can simply use the math.sum() for this purpose.
math.sum()


The sum function returns the sliding sum of last y values of x.

is_down = open < open[1]

down_cnt = math.sum(is_down ? 1 : 0, 5)

This will return you the sum of downtrend candles within the last 5 candles.
